How to delete duplicates in two columns where its for a situation where unique values will be in each cell

How do you delete duplicates between both columns so that there will stay just number 4 in A column? Please note that 2 column values are compared together and the same values should be removed in the end thanks
So far i tried removing duplicate in excel but it doesn't work due to the unique value between the rows not being the same, e.g A2 and B2 is 2 and 3 respectively.

Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell D1
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:B4,1),,1)


So, the above formula won't delete, instead it would return output which are not duplicates that is those which have appeared exactly once.

